# Process on one server calling console app on another server - DirectoryNotFoundException

Tags: c#, .net, networking, localhost

I developed a console app that takes some parameters.  In this console app I specify paths to a logging directory, persistence directory, etc...  We are going to have a process on a completely different server which is going to make a call to my console app and start it.  When we test this its currently erroring.  The issue is because the paths aren't valid.  It's like its trying to map the logging directory to the caller server path instead of the path where the exe is deployed to.  So for instance I have serverA and serverB.  My console app is deployed to serverB.  ServerA will be calling my exe on serverB.  When the console app starts it errors with DirectoryNotFoundException.  I am specifying the path as L:\Logs\log.log or as \localhost\l\Logs\log.log.  It seems to me whats happening is that since ServerA is calling my exe on ServerB it thinks L: or localhost is ServerA, when I want it to be ServerB.  Any ideas?

Comment: This question was highly confusing. I wonder whether you think a process on one machine can start a process on another machine just by placing the executables on a drive that belongs to that other machine. It doesn't work that way at all. The started process will be running on the same machine as the process that started it, and of course both processes will have the same view of disks and paths and whatever.

Comment: I'm not sure how to word it any better.  So I have a console application and I deploy it to directory on serverB(\\ServerB\N\MyApp\MyApp.exe).  Now something will trigger a job to start on a different server, ServerA, that will call my console application.  So to test this if I go to the command line on serverA I can execute my console app by calling "\\ServerB\N\MyApp\MyApp.exe".  And this does start my console app.  But my code is setting log path and various other paths in C# code.  So I have a line like var logFile = "\\localhost\L\Logs\log.log".  This throws a directoryNotFoundException

Comment: Ah! That string literal isn't what you think it is. Prepend the string with @, like this `@"\\localhost\L\Logs\log.log"`.

Comment: I have also tried setting logFile = L:\Logs\log.log.  It also throws a directoryNotFoundException.  The log path should exist on ServerB where my console app is deployed to.  But it's behaving that its trying to look for the log path on ServerA, where I am calling from.

Comment: Furthermore I get this to work if I log in to ServerB and go to the commandline and execute my exe from the same server.  It finds the log directory just fine.  It only errors when I'm calling from a different server.

Comment: Yes, that's right. The process is running on serverA, so it's the paths as seen on serverA that the process will be using.

Comment: That's right too. When you run the process on serverB, then the process will see the paths as you see them on serverB. That's just the way it works. You have to look at it from the viewpoint of which machine the process is running on, and disregard where the executable is actually placed, because that's completely irrelevant.

Comment: So how can I force it to use the local drives on the server where my exe is being hosted?

Comment: I've tried using UNC path, using the specific server name...so logPath = \\serverB\L\Logs\log.log.  But this screws some other things.  It starts thinking that dlls are on remote servers even though they are on the same server.  But since I specify \\ServerB\L\... it thinks that's a remote server and won't load dlls because it won't load remote dlls.

Comment: ServerB is a remote server in this context. Read my first comment again, and the rest too. If you can edit your question and add some details about what it is you want to achieve, then perhaps somebody will post a good answer. As it is now, there's so many solutions I can think of, but there are pros and cons that depend on the scenario. What you want to achieve may not be that straightforward.

Comment: I just want my console app to be able to log.  I specify a log path.  The console app is deployed to ServerB.  I want to log to the L drive on ServerB.  If I specify logpath = L:\Logs this doesn't work because I am calling it from serverA.  So how do I force my console app to log to the L drive on the same server it's deployed to?

Comment: If you don't actually want the console app to run on serverB, but only log to some disk location on serverB, then from serverA you can map the disk location in question. You need to share out that disk location from serverB,, in order for serverA to map to it.

Comment: You can possibly also use this syntax to reach drives on serverB from serverA: \\serverB\c$\somedir

Comment: A process can actually start a process on another machine, but it is not as trivial as starting a process on the same machine, and does not involve the same calls. I don't recommend this approach if all you need to do is log to some disk on a remote machine.

Comment: When you execute your console app, it runs on the execution context provided by the machine where the action of starting the program is taken, regardless of where the program you are trying to execute is sitting. From the point of view of the OS, you are requesting execution of a program and you tell it where the program is (regardless of whether the path is local). The OS tries to run it by loading its dependencies. That's when you may see security errors, but it all happens local to the request for execution.

Comment: What's the intent? Why do you want to launch that in another machine? What will the program do? We can't help you without knowing what you are trying to achieve. You are telling us you have a problem and showing us the bad behavior but you are not telling us what the the program is expected to do.

Comment: So the console app is simply kicking off an nservicebus message.  The server that is hosting the console app also has a backend nservicebus integration to handle the message.  The message that gets raised is simply triggering the backend to do a file copy and some other things.  The console app is deployed to this server (as well as the backend) because it contains all the nservicebus dependencies.  Now on my other server that is calling my console app this server is used for some other business processes.  Some business process occurs triggering the need to raise an nservicebus message.

Comment: If I deploy my console app to the same server as the caller it won't have the nservicebus dependencies like ravendb, etc...